# I dont know why my list view shows extra background at the end of list

Tags: android, listview

I'm using a list view in my fragment activity. I don't know why this extra space background is shown at the end of my list view. All the items are shown correctly but the list view shows me background at the end of the list as shown in the image below which I don't want to show; kindly help me.

[image: Image of my List view as shown in this link .]

**my layout xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.TimeSheetFragment">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:layout_height="0dp">


            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/timesheetW"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sfcompacttextmedium"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2">






        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>









        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_t_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/currentmonthbg"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_80sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_170sdp">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="October 2019"
                android:id="@+id/month_timesheet"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sfcompacttextmedium"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/warning_img"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/warning"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                />


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin_timesheet_pics"
                android:layout_below="@+id/warning_img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_35sdp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">



                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_55sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_52sdp"
                    android:id="@+id/timeWorkDaysIcon"
                    android:src="@drawable/workdaysicon"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/borderlarge"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:id="@+id/timeLeavesIcon"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/leavesicon"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/borderlarge"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:id="@+id/timeSicknessIcon"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/sickness"
                    />






            </LinearLayout>




            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin_timesheet_text"
                android:layout_below="@id/lin_timesheet_pics"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_35sdp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">




                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:text="25"
                    android:id="@+id/txtWorkDays"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/sfcompacttextsemibold"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/bordersmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_14sdp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:fontFamily="@font/sfcompacttextsemibold"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorGreen"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_1sdp"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="07"
                    android:id="@+id/txtLeaves"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/bordersmall"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_14sdp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:fontFamily="@font/sfcompacttextsemibold"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorOrange"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="04"
                    android:id="@+id/txtSickness"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    />






            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel_t_main"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer_lv"
        android:id="@+id/listViewTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
        />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/footer_lv"
        android:background="@drawable/menubgg"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back"
            android:id="@+id/backTm"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/addTm"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menuTm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menuicon"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**my adapter code:**

```
package com.ndbsoft.cozati.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.ndbsoft.cozati.Models.Timesheet;
import com.ndbsoft.cozati.R;
import com.ndbsoft.cozati.utils;

import java.util.List;

public class AdapterTimesheetList extends BaseAdapter {

    String monthName;
    private Context context;
    private List<Timesheet> timelist;

    public AdapterTimesheetList(Context context, List<Timesheet> timelist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.timelist = timelist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return timelist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return timelist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return timelist.get(position).getTimeSheetId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view33= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.timesheet_list_item,parent,false);
        Timesheet timeSheett=timelist.get(position);


        if (timelist.get(position).getStatusCode().equals("timesheet-waiting_validation")){

            if (utils.lang.equals("fr")){
                ((RelativeLayout)view33.findViewById(R.id.background_timesheet_list)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.draft_list_bg_fr);
            }else if (utils.lang.equals("en")){
                ((RelativeLayout)view33.findViewById(R.id.background_timesheet_list)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.draft_list_bg);
            }

        }
        else if (timelist.get(position).getStatusCode().equals("timesheet-manager-approved")){
            if (utils.lang.equals("fr")){
                ((RelativeLayout)view33.findViewById(R.id.background_timesheet_list)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.approved_list_bg_fr);
            }else if (utils.lang.equals("en")){
                ((RelativeLayout)view33.findViewById(R.id.background_timesheet_list)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.approved_list_bg);
            }

           }
        else if (timelist.get(position).getStatusCode().equals("timesheet-refused")){

            if (utils.lang.equals("fr")){
                ((RelativeLayout)view33.findViewById(R.id.background_timesheet_list)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.refused_list_bg_fr);
            }else if (utils.lang.equals("en")){
                ((RelativeLayout)view33.findViewById(R.id.background_timesheet_list)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.refused_list_bg);
            }

        }
        else {

        }

//        String monthname=(String)android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", new Date());
//        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        Timesheet timesheetObj = timelist.get(position);


        String month = String.valueOf(timesheetObj.getMonth());
        if (month.equals("1")){
            monthName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.janu);
        }
        else if (month.equals("2")){
            monthName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.feb);
        }
        else if (month.equals("3")){
            monthName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.march);
        }
        else if (month.equals("4")){
            monthName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.april);
        }
        else if (month.equals("5")){
            monthName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.may);
        }
        else if (month.equals("6")){
            monthName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.june);
        }
        else if (month.equals("7")){
            monthName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.july);
        }
        else if (month.equals("8")){
            monthName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.aug);
        }
        else if (month.equals("9")){
            monthName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.sept);
        }
        else if (month.equals("10")){
            monthName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.octo);
        }
        else if (month.equals("11")){
            monthName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.nov);
        }
        else if (month.equals("12")){
            monthName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.decm);
        }



        ((TextView)view33.findViewById(R.id.txt_date_li)).setText("Timesheet "+monthName +" "+timesheetObj.getYear());
        ((TextView)view33.findViewById(R.id.txt_mission_li2)).setText(String.valueOf( " " +timeSheett.getMissionName()));
        ((TextView)view33.findViewById(R.id.txt_workdays_li2)).setText(String.valueOf(timesheetObj.getTotalPresence()));
        ((TextView)view33.findViewById(R.id.txt_leaves_li2)).setText("0");
        ((TextView)view33.findViewById(R.id.txt_sickness_li2)).setText("0");


        return view33;
    }

}
```

And here is my code :

```
        final RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, utils.Base_URl+"/timesheet/resource/"+utils.user_detail.getResourceId(),
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {

                            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);

                            if (jsonArray.length() == 0){
                                progress.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.listEmpty, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else {

                                for (int i=0 ; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++){

                                    JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    int timesheetId=jsonObject.getInt("timesheetId");

                                    if (jsonObject.getString("resourceId") == null){
                                        resourceId = 0;
                                    }
                                    else if (jsonObject.getString("resourceId").equals("null")){
                                        resourceId = 0;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        resourceId = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("resourceId"));
                                    }

                                    int month=jsonObject.getInt("month");
                                    int year=jsonObject.getInt("year");
//                                int statusId=jsonObject.getInt("statusId");

                                    if (jsonObject.getString("missionId") == null){
                                         missionId = 0;
                                    }
                                    else if (jsonObject.getString("missionId").equals("null")){
                                        missionId = 0;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        missionId = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("missionId"));
                                    }

//                                    int missionId=jsonObject.getInt("missionId");
                                    String firstName=jsonObject.getString("firstName");
                                    String lastName=jsonObject.getString("lastName");
                                    String monthLabel=jsonObject.getString("monthLabel");
                                    String statusCode=jsonObject.getString("statusCode");
                                    String missionName=jsonObject.getString("missionName");
                                    double totalNightShift=jsonObject.getDouble("totalNightShift");
                                    double totalExtraHourNight=jsonObject.getDouble("totalExtraHourNight");
                                    double totalExtraHours=jsonObject.getDouble("totalExtraHours");
                                    double totalPresence=jsonObject.getDouble("totalPresence");

                                    String monthname=(String)android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", new Date());
                                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    monthLabel22.setText(monthname);

                                    Timesheet timeSheet = new Timesheet();
                                    timeSheet.setTimeSheetId(timesheetId);
                                    timeSheet.setResourceId(resourceId);
                                    timeSheet .setMonth(month);
                                    timeSheet .setYear(year);
//                                timeSheet.setStatusId(statusId);
                                    timeSheet .setMissionId(missionId);
                                    timeSheet.setFirstName(firstName);
                                    timeSheet.setLastName(lastName);
                                    timeSheet.setMonthLabel(monthLabel);
                                    timeSheet .setStatusCode(statusCode);
                                    timeSheet.setMissionName(missionName);
                                    timeSheet .setTotalNightShift(totalNightShift);
                                    timeSheet .setTotalExtraHourNight(totalExtraHourNight);
                                    timeSheet.setTotalExtraHours(totalExtraHours);
                                    timeSheet.setTotalPresence(totalPresence);

                                    timeSheetList.add(timeSheet);
                                    timeSheetListTotal.setAdapter(new AdapterTimesheetList(getContext(),timeSheetList));
                                    progress.dismiss();

                                }
                            }


                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            progress.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.someWrong, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progress.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.someWrong, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers =  new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Accept","application/json");
                headers.put("Authorization",utils.bear+utils.user_token);
                return headers;
            }
        };
```

Comment: show `R.layout.timesheet_list_item,parent`

Answer (score 1):

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/footer_lv"
        android:background="@drawable/menubgg"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"> // set this to  wrap_content.
```